# XHR CORS policy firebase storage upload file

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have a problem with firebase storage. I want to upload file on firebase storage but the CORS policy blocked me.

I had set the cors.json file with this information:

```json
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET", "POST"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

and I had run this commande gsutil cors get gs://bucketname.

When I run the command gsutil cors get gs://joyfinder-6ae54.appspot.com I have this return :

[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "POST"], "origin": ["*"]}]

But when I try to upload file on my firebase storage I have this error :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/%22my-project.appspot.com%22%2C/o?name=avatar%2FZ3njUHzScEY1UfdIFumNjUJz8wf1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I don't know what to do to solve the problem.

Can you please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: That error URL has `%22my-project.appspot.com%22%2C` in the URL, which decodes as `"my-project.appspot.com",` this looks like the object you are passing to `initializeApp()` has bad data in it. If you are filling the object in from environment variables, I'd look there.